# I'm trying to set up OBS Studio on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: drivers, video

I'm unable to record on OBS Studio. When I try to record, I get a message: Failed to open NVENC codec: Function not implemented  Please check your video drivers are up to date.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a MacBook Pro 9,1. Intel core i7-3720 QM CPU @ 2.60Hz x 8.
It's not dual boot. Linux is the only OS installed.
Help?

TIA!
db

Comment: Possible: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/obs-failed-to-open-nvenc-codec-function-not-implemented.124430/

Comment: Got it, Thanks to user535733! Another simpleton moves up a notch ;)